# Burp DOM-based Open Redirect

Tags: appsec, burp-suite

When I sent a request such as:

```
GET /500.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/error.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
```

Burp reports "The application may be vulnerable to DOM-based open redirection:
Data is read from document.location.pathname and passed to the 'open()' function of an XMLHttpRequest object via the following statements:

```
var action = theForm.action || document.location.pathname, fragmentIndex = action.indexOf('#');
path = action.substr(0, queryIndex);
domain = path.substr(0, slashAfterDomain);
action = domain + encodeURI(path) + query;
xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);
```

Is this a false positive? How to create a valid PoC for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code snippet, the URL for the POST request is either taken from the `action` attribute of a particular form or the current path. If the current path is used, this is harmless, because no actual redirect happens. If the `action` attribute is used, it depends on whether and how much an attacker can influence this attribute. As long as the domain is hard-coded (or equal to the current domain), there is no risk, because an attacker cannot trigger a redirect to their own website.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear!